# Remove Horizontal ScrollBar from Telerik RadTextBox in IE

Tags: asp.net, css, telerik

Is there a way (preferably without javascript) to prevent a TextBox control from overflowing and displaying a horizontal scroll bar (I want a vertical scroll only) ?  I've tried Wrap="true" and a host of other things

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="tx_Subj" Runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"  
    CssClass="SubjTextBox" width="100%" style="position:relative;"  Skin="Metro">
</telerik:RadTextBox>

.SubjTextBox 
{ 
    height:63px; 
    width: 100% !important; 
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
    overflow:hidden; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try the `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` settings?

```
.SubjTextBox  {
      height:63px;
      width: 100% !important;
      padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
      overflow-x: hidden;  
}
```

Also, make sure that your CSS is actually getting applied to the object. Sometimes the Rad controls generate more markup than you think.

Comment: Did you validate that the styles are getting applied, using Firebug or similar tools?

Comment: Yeah I'm looking at that now and I think that might be the problem, your right tho its hard to tell with the number of wrappers

Comment: Color me shocked that IE isn't working. ;) `overflow-x` is supported in IE, so it should work!

Comment: Yeah Right, I'm marking this as the answer as it should be the answer if IE didn't suck so very badly.  thanks